# Elementary Gnome tweak not working

Tags: gnome

Hello I was wondering if anyone else here is having trouble using Gnome tweak for Elementary

Is was working for awhile but all of a sudden it will not open. I have tried removing it and them reinstalling it but the same out come

Thanks for any help with this

Answer (score 3):

As Philip Scott (the tweaks dev) replies [here](https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks/issues/115#issuecomment-558449769), the issue is being taken care of. So I guess we'll have to wait a little until the update will be deployed in the PPA.

Comment: It's not working after the new update.

Comment: Mine works after the update.

Comment: It works on my computer also, but I did applied a fix from a comment in the issue into github. After the update just the launcher option of changing the columns and rows dissappeared. Later today will try it on another machine without the fix from the comment there and will comment if it is the reason